# TSQL - export query to xls /xslx / csv

Tags: t-sql, excel, export

I have a complicated dynamic query in TSQL that I want to export to Excel. 
[The result table contains fields with text longer than 255 chars, if it matters]

I know I can export result using the Management Studio menus but I want to do it automatically by code. Do you know how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at [sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx). This allows you to send an email from your query after it's run, containing an attached CSV of the resultset. Obviously the viability of this method would be dependent on how big your resultset is.

Example from the linked document:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'AdventureWorks2008R2 Administrator',
@recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
@query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.WorkOrder
              WHERE DueDate > ''2006-04-30''
              AND  DATEDIFF(dd, ''2006-04-30'', DueDate) < 2' ,
@subject = 'Work Order Count',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using that option at other parts of my system but this time I really need the system to output csv xls file so employees without a lot of technical knowledge could simply open it.

Comment: You should be able to get this method to output as a normal csv, by setting the results separator field. We use this currently in one system, it emails non-technical users a csv file that they can open in Excel. See http://dbaspot.com/forums/sqlserver-programming/383582-sp_send_dbmail-attachment-issue.html for a discussion of how to implement, otherwise I'll get back to you in a couple of days when I'm back in the office to see our implementation

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use bcp which you can call from the command line - check out the examples in that reference, and in particular see the info on the -t argument which you can use to set the field terminator (for CSV). There's this linked reference on [Specifying Field and Row Terminators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485.aspx).

Or, directly using TSQL you could use OPENROWSET [as explained here by Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/08/sql-server-2005-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-microsoft-excel-datasheet/).

**Update:**
Re;: 2008 64Bit & OPENROWSET - I wasn't aware of that, quick dig throws up [this on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/711a6921-bebb-46f7-acd9-065bd6a6cfce) with a link given. Any help?

Aside from that, other options include writing an SSIS package or using SQL CLR to write an export procedure in .NET to call directly from SQL. Or, you *could* call bcp from TSQL via xp_cmdshell - you have to enable it though which will open up the possible "attack surface" of SQL Server. I suggest checking out [this discussion](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic378524-338-1.aspx#bm708923).

Comment: Thanks. I prefer doing it directly using TSQL. problem is that the Pinal's method does not work for SQL server 2008 64bit.

Comment: So, If I got it straight - the button line is that there's no solution to that, I guess. The funny thing is that I managed to produce a great csv file using the menu, there's got to be a way.

Comment: @Or Shachar - I'm pretty sure when you do it via the UI, it's just calling BCP. So you can do that from BCP as above, using xp_cmdshell.

Answer (score 1):

Some approaches here: [SQL Server Excel Workbench](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-excel-workbench/)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to accept a dynamic query and save the results to disk so I can download it through the web application.

insert into data source didn't work out for me because of continued effort in getting it to work.

Eventually I went with sending the query to powershell from SSMS
Read my post here
[How do I create a document on the server by running an existing storedprocedure or the sql statement of that procedure on a R2008 sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937730/how-do-i-create-a-document-on-the-server-by-running-an-existing-storedprocedure)

Single quotes however was a problem and at first i didn't trim my query and write it on one line so it had line breaks in sql studio which actually matters.