# export csv from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, csv

Is there a way in sql 2008 stored procedure to dump data to a file in CSV with column headers?  Do i have to use BCP?  I used to use openrowset for this but there are no jet drives on 64bit versions of sql 2008.

I don't want to do this from a command line using sqlcmd  It has to be done in the stored proc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567410/i-need-best-practice-in-t-sql-export-data-to-csv-with-header and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591551/tsql-export-query-to-xls-xslx-csv

Answer (score 0):

**64bit Driver:** 
Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d

**Details on how to use here:** 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/33436d82-085c-43e4-b991-a2d0d701c8fc

**Answer from Link:** 
There is now a 64bit driver available, you can download it here:

Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d

This will register a driver which is listed under Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> Providers with the name
"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" which you must use as the Provider string.

Connection string for 64-bit OLEDB Provider:
For CSV / Text files, Add "Text" to the Extended Properties of the OLEDB connection string.
Important: With the new 12.0 driver and text files the schema.ini file is compulsory in the directory of the csv/text file, otherwise you will receive a "Could not find installable ISAM" error. 
schema.ini documentation can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(VS.85).aspx

If you are connecting to Microsoft Office Excel data, add “Excel 14.0” to the Extended Properties of the OLEDB connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example:

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/sql-server-data-to-a-jet-database/

I am exporting to a Jet database (aka, "Microsoft Access").

You can probably convert to Excel fairly easily.

But the code would be able to be put into a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

We have used this code successfully in a number of instances:

http://prosqlserver.com/blog/2011/07/02/sqlclr-procedure-to-export-query-sp-results-into-csv/